Парсинг TXT файла с расписанием
Есть документ с таким содержимым:
| Понедельник | 9:00  | Математика | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Понедельник | 10:40  | Математика | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Понедельник | 12:40  | Математика | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Вторник | 10:40  | История | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Вторник | 12:40  | История/Обществознание | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Вторник | 14:20  | История/Обществознание | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Вторник | 16:20  | Безопасность жизнедеятельности | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Среда | 9:00  | Русский язык | Лекция (17.01, 31.01, 14.02, 28.02, 13.03, 27.03, 10.04, 24.04, 08.05) | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Среда | 12:40  | Литература | Лекция (12.01-14.06) | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Среда | 14:20  | Литература | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Четверг | 9:00  | География/Биология/Химия | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Четверг | 10:40  | География/Биология/Химия | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Четверг | 12:40  | География/Биология/Химия | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Четверг | 14:20  | География/Биология/Химия | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Пятница | 9:00  | Физика | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Пятница | 10:40  | Физическая культура | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Пятница | 12:40  | Физика | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович |

Его необходимо спарсить и отправить в базу данных использую aiomysql для работы с бд, даже предположить не могу как на практике это реализовать. Вот что я попытался сделать:
def parse_schedule(text):
    """
    Разделяет сообщение на составляющие: день недели, время, предмет, дополнительная информация и преподаватель.
    Возвращает список из этих составляющих.
    """

    day_of_week = text.split("|")[0]
    time = text.split("|")[1].split()[0]  # время — это первый элемент после разделения строки по пробелу
    subject = text.split("|")[2].strip()  # предмет — это третий элемент после разделения строки по |, без пробелов в начале и конце
    additional_info = text.split("|")[3].strip()
    teacher = text.split("|")[-1].strip()  # преподаватель — это последний элемент после разделения строки по |, без пробелов в начале и конце

    return [day_of_week, time, subject, additional_info, teacher]


Правильно на мой взгляд регулярками, но ровно с таким же успехом можно сделать через обычный .split("|")

Можно пример кода? Долго уже вожусь с этой дичью

Декомпозиция - слышали о таком? Поделите задачу на маленькие шажки. Питоном 1: открыть файл, 2: прочитать данные построчно. 3: читая строку сохранятьее в какой то список. 4: научиться разбивать строку по определенному символу, что бы получить список данных(ну или словарь). 5: подключиться к БД. 6: вызывать скрипт для вставки записей в БД. 0: Сделать это самому по учебнику.  Так что начинайте изучение с 1 пункта и последовательно идите. Будут ошибки - приходите, поможем(если сможем)

@zavsc, обновите вопрос и покажите пример вашего решения, возможно вы были близки к решению.

@kristal обновил

Вообще вам стоит понять как ваш код работает. Метод split(pattern) разделяет строку по патерну переданному в него и возвращает список строк. То есть, для строки | Понедельник | 9:00  | Математика | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович | c.split("|") вернётся такой список:
['', ' Понедельник ', ' 9:00  ', ' Математика ', ' Практика ', ' Иванов Иван Иванович ', '']

Пустая строка '' возвращается по причине того что перед | ничего не стоит или наоборот. Далее, как работать с коллекциями, я думаю, вы должны понимать. Если обрезать лишние пустые строки вы получите желаемый результат. Или, в вашем случае, если хотите записать результат в переменные, можно сделать срез:
day_of_week, time, subject, additional_info, teacher = text.split("|")[1:-1]

У меня же вышло примерно так:
schedule_string = """
| Понедельник | 9:00  | Математика | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Понедельник | 10:40  | Математика | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Понедельник | 12:40  | Математика | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Вторник | 10:40  | История | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Вторник | 12:40  | История/Обществознание | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Вторник | 14:20  | История/Обществознание | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Вторник | 16:20  | Безопасность жизнедеятельности | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Среда | 9:00  | Русский язык | Лекция (17.01, 31.01, 14.02, 28.02, 13.03, 27.03, 10.04, 24.04, 08.05) | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Среда | 12:40  | Литература | Лекция (12.01-14.06) | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Среда | 14:20  | Литература | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Четверг | 9:00  | География/Биология/Химия | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Четверг | 10:40  | География/Биология/Химия | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Четверг | 12:40  | География/Биология/Химия | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Четверг | 14:20  | География/Биология/Химия | Лекция | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Пятница | 9:00  | Физика | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Пятница | 10:40  | Физическая культура | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович |
| Пятница | 12:40  | Физика | Практика | Иванов Иван Иванович |
"""


def parse_schedule(line):
    return [i.strip() for i in line.split("|") if i != ""]


schedule_list = [parse_schedule(i) for i in schedule_string.split("\n") if i != ""]


Я это использую в связке с aiogram. Пользователь отправляет расписание в таком формате дальше оно должно парсится и записывать всё в базу данных. Я ещё сначала думал может телеграмм что-то не так с моим сообщением делает

@zavsc для таких случаев стоит использовать дебагер и проходить по коду построчно. Если ответ вас устраивает, то не забывайте его принять.

Спасибо вам огромное, принял ответ!
